# Java serializer/deserializer for List<Long>

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I need to make serializer and deserializer, because I get this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Long` out of START_ARRAY token
```

And I make it:

```
public class CalculatorIDsDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Long> {
    @Override
    public Long deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser,
                            final DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException {
        String dataString = jsonParser.getText();
        return Long.parseLong(dataString);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CalculatorIDsSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Long>{
    @Override
    public void serialize(Long aLong, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(Long.toString(aLong));
    }
}
```

but now I have this error:

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

And I make it for:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CalculatorIDsDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = CalculatorIDsSerializer.class)
private List<Long> insuranceFileIDs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Some tips how to solve it? I have no more ideas after a few hours. Thaks

**Update:** I change it to this, but I get same error :(

```
public class CalculatorIDsDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<Long>> {

    @Override
    public List<Long> deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser,
                                  final DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException {

        String dataString = jsonParser.getText();
        List<Long> ids = null;
        ids.add(Long.parseLong(dataString));
        return ids;
    }
}
```

**Update2:**

```
public class CalculatorIDsSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<Long>>{

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<Long> longs, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        longs.forEach(item ->{
            try {
                jsonGenerator.writeString(Long.toString(item));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CalculatorIDsDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<Long>> {
    @Override
    public List<Long> deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser,
                                  final DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException {
        String dataString = jsonParser.getText();
        List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        ids.add(Long.parseLong(dataString));
        return ids;
    }
}
```

And i get: Problem deserializing property 'insuranceFileIDs' (expected type: [simple type, class java.lang.Long]; actual type: `java.util.ArrayList`), problem: argument type mismatch

Comment: Could it be because you return a `Long` instead of a `List<Long>` in your deserializer? Because your field `insuranceFileIDs` is of the type `List<Long>`

Comment: I change it to:

Comment: Your list `ids` is `null`. So `ids.add(...)` should throw an exception. Try `return List.of(Long.parseLong(dataString));` or initialize your list like `List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: More advice....? Please

Comment: Maybe you should not initialize the field `insuranceFileIDs` with an `ArrayList`. Try to remove the initialization. But I think the deserializer is ok now.

Comment: The same problem continues...:(

Comment: Does your deserializer/serializer ever get called? If try to debug?

Comment: Yes, is called. I change serializer, because i get error from there.

Comment: Can you add +1 please? I still don't have a functional solution, maybe someone else can advise us.